# Creating multiple dimesion array

Tags: javascript

I need something like this:

```
var fruits[1] = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits[2] = ["Banana"];
fruits[1].push("Lemon");
fruits[2].push("Orange");
```

But this is not working in javascript.

Is there a way to achive this mechanism in javascript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, initialize `fruits` itself as an array

```js
var fruits = [];
fruits[1] = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits[2] = ["Banana"];
fruits[1].push("Lemon");
fruits[2].push("Orange");

console.log(fruits);
```

Comment: I have one more question: Is there a something like this: fruits[1].remove("Lemon") ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/remove-a-specific-element-from-an-array @TolgayToklar

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
var fruits = []; //declared a blank array

fruits.push("Banana"); //adding 1st item
fruits.push("Orange"); //adding 2nd item
fruits.push("Apple");  //adding 3rd item
fruits.push("Mango");  //adding 4th item

//if you want to update any item then simply do the following
fruits[2] = "Lemon"
```